# I need help getting price changed woocoormerce from user input

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I set a custom price based on user input? This custom price is hard coded. Any suggestions? Something like function add_custom_price( $cart_object, $custom_price )

```
<code>add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object,$custom_price ) {
    $custom_price = $variable_from_input; // This will be my custom input variable 
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}</code>
```